# How can I create an Item Frequency Plot for association rule data? By converting to data frame or numeric?

Tags: r, csv

I have given the code that the rules are generated.I would like to create an item frequency histogram plot but ıt didn't work.

```
library(arules)
library(arulesViz)
library(rattle)

x <- read.table("C:/Users/toshıba pc/Desktop/Kitap2.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
y <- as.matrix(x)

rules <- apriori(y, parameter = list(supp = 0.1, conf = 0.8))

itemFrequencyPlot(rules, support = 0.1, cex.names = 0.8)
```

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
>               unable to find an inherited method for function ‘itemFrequencyPlot’ for signature ‘"rules"’

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`itemFrequencyPlot` is not defined for `rules`. You can use

```
itemFrequencyPlot(items(rules))
```

to get the frequency of the items in the rules, but I am not sure that this will give you the results you want.

Comment: It really worked so thank you so much @michaelHahsler